# AFTER DELETE trigger fires only if a DELETE is executed on a db query but not on EF Core

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-delete, cascade, ef-core-7.0

I have two master-detail tables with a one-to-many relationship. I want to let a trigger fire after a deletion has happened, whether it has been as a cascade action (deleting the master by its PK) or by a specific action (deleting the detail by its PK).

Here's my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_update_stocks]
ON [dbo].[WarehouseComponentLoadRows]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF ((SELECT TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL()) > 1) 
       RETURN;

    DECLARE @Id BIGINT
    DECLARE @WarehouseId INT
    DECLARE @ComponentId INT
    DECLARE @ColorId INT
    DECLARE @Quantity DECIMAL (18,6)

    DECLARE deleted_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
        SELECT 
            Id, WarehouseId, 
            ComponentId, ColorId,
            Quantity
        FROM 
            DELETED

    OPEN deleted_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM deleted_cursor into @Id, @WarehouseId, @ComponentId, @ColorId, @Quantity

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[WarehouseComponents]
        SET [dbo].[WarehouseComponents].[StockQuantity] = [dbo].[WarehouseComponents].[StockQuantity] - @Quantity,
            [dbo].[WarehouseComponents].[AvailableQuantity] = [dbo].[WarehouseComponents].[AvailableQuantity] - @Quantity
        FROM
            [dbo].[WarehouseComponents]
        WHERE 
            [dbo].[WarehouseComponents].[WarehouseId] =  @WarehouseId 
            AND [dbo].[WarehouseComponents].[ComponentId] =  @ComponentId 
            AND [dbo].[WarehouseComponents].[ColorId] =  @ColorId

        FETCH NEXT FROM deleted_cursor INTO @Id, @WarehouseId, @ComponentId, @ColorId, @Quantity
  END

  CLOSE deleted_cursor
  DEALLOCATE deleted_cursor

  DECLARE inserted_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
      SELECT Id
          , WarehouseId
          , ComponentId
          , ColorId
          , Quantity
      FROM INSERTED

  OPEN inserted_cursor
  FETCH NEXT FROM inserted_cursor into @Id, @WarehouseId, @ComponentId, @ColorId, @Quantity

  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN

  UPDATE [dbo].[WarehouseComponents]
  SET
      [dbo].[WarehouseComponents].[StockQuantity] = [dbo].[WarehouseComponents].[StockQuantity] + @Quantity,
      [dbo].[WarehouseComponents].[AvailableQuantity] = [dbo].[WarehouseComponents].[AvailableQuantity] + @Quantity
  FROM
      [dbo].[WarehouseComponents]
  WHERE [dbo].[WarehouseComponents].[WarehouseId] =  @WarehouseId AND [dbo].[WarehouseComponents].[ComponentId] =  @ComponentId AND [dbo].[WarehouseComponents].[ColorId] =  @ColorId

  FETCH NEXT FROM inserted_cursor into @Id, @WarehouseId, @ComponentId, @ColorId, @Quantity
END

CLOSE inserted_cursor
DEALLOCATE inserted_cursor
END
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WarehouseComponentLoadRows] 
     ENABLE TRIGGER [tr_update_stocks]
GO
```

Here you find my master table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WarehouseComponentLoads]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SupplierId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedAt] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [UpdatedAt] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [UpdatedBy] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WarehouseComponentLoads] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_WarehouseComponentLoads] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
                      ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_WarehouseComponentLoads_SupplierId] 
ON [dbo].[WarehouseComponentLoads] ([SupplierId] ASC)
       WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
             SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
             ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WarehouseComponentLoads] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_WarehouseComponentLoads_Subjects_SupplierId] 
        FOREIGN KEY([SupplierId])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Subjects] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WarehouseComponentLoads] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_WarehouseComponentLoads_Subjects_SupplierId]
GO
```

Here's my details table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WarehouseComponentLoadRows]
(
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [WarehouseComponentLoadId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [WarehouseId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ComponentId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ColorId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Quantity] [decimal](18, 6) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WarehouseComponentLoadRows] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_WarehouseComponentLoadRows] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
                      ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_WarehouseComponentLoadRows_ColorId] 
ON [dbo].[WarehouseComponentLoadRows] ([ColorId] ASC)
       WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
             SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
             ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_WarehouseComponentLoadRows_ComponentId] 
ON [dbo].[WarehouseComponentLoadRows] ([ComponentId] ASC)
       WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
             SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
             ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_WarehouseComponentLoadRows_WarehouseComponentLoadId] 
ON [dbo].[WarehouseComponentLoadRows] ([WarehouseComponentLoadId] ASC)
       WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
             SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
             ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_WarehouseComponentLoadRows_WarehouseId] 
ON [dbo].[WarehouseComponentLoadRows] ([WarehouseId] ASC)
       WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
             SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
             ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WarehouseComponentLoadRows]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_WarehouseComponentLoadRows_Colors_ColorId] 
        FOREIGN KEY([ColorId])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Colors] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WarehouseComponentLoadRows] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_WarehouseComponentLoadRows_Colors_ColorId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WarehouseComponentLoadRows] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_WarehouseComponentLoadRows_Components_ComponentId] 
        FOREIGN KEY([ComponentId])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Components] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WarehouseComponentLoadRows] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_WarehouseComponentLoadRows_Components_ComponentId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WarehouseComponentLoadRows] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_WarehouseComponentLoadRows_WarehouseComponentLoads_WarehouseComponentLoadId] 
        FOREIGN KEY([WarehouseComponentLoadId])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[WarehouseComponentLoads] ([Id])
            ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WarehouseComponentLoadRows] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_WarehouseComponentLoadRows_WarehouseComponentLoads_WarehouseComponentLoadId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WarehouseComponentLoadRows] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_WarehouseComponentLoadRows_Warehouses_WarehouseId] 
        FOREIGN KEY([WarehouseId])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Warehouses] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WarehouseComponentLoadRows] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_WarehouseComponentLoadRows_Warehouses_WarehouseId]
GO
```

Here you find the stockings table to be updated:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WarehouseComponents]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [WarehouseId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ComponentId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ColorId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StockQuantity] [decimal](18, 6) NOT NULL,
    [AvailableQuantity] [decimal](18, 6) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WarehouseComponents] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_WarehouseComponents] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
                      ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_WarehouseComponents_ColorId] 
ON [dbo].[WarehouseComponents] ([ColorId] ASC)
       WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
             SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF,  
             ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_WarehouseComponents_ComponentId] 
ON [dbo].[WarehouseComponents] ([ComponentId] ASC)
       WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
             SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
             ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_WarehouseComponents_WarehouseId] 
ON [dbo].[WarehouseComponents] ([WarehouseId] ASC)
       WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
             SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
             ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WarehouseComponents] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_WarehouseComponents_Colors_ColorId] 
        FOREIGN KEY([ColorId])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Colors] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WarehouseComponents] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_WarehouseComponents_Colors_ColorId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WarehouseComponents] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_WarehouseComponents_Components_ComponentId] 
        FOREIGN KEY([ComponentId])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Components] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WarehouseComponents] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_WarehouseComponents_Components_ComponentId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WarehouseComponents] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_WarehouseComponents_Warehouses_WarehouseId] 
        FOREIGN KEY([WarehouseId])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Warehouses] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WarehouseComponents] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_WarehouseComponents_Warehouses_WarehouseId]
GO
```

Basically I am experiencing this issue: whenever I insert or update a entire master-detail entity using EF 7 everything works fine. Everything goes well also if I insert, update or delete a single row in the details table. But if I delete a master entity by its PK from the context and I save changes, it's like the trigger doesn't fire and while the master-detail records are correctly removed, the stockings aren't updated. This only happens from within the EF context. If I try to delete the master row by its PK from within SQL Server by a simple query, the cascade behavior is correctly applied and the trigger fires as expected, adjusting the stockings.

Please, consider that my fluent APIs for the my context contain a specific configuration to let EF know that I am using a trigger, as follows:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<WarehouseComponentLoadRow>()
             .ToTable(tb => tb.HasTrigger("tr_update_stocks"));
```

Interestingly also, if I try to "manually" remove the children rows and then the parent rows within the same transaction scope (namely, before calling a `SaveChangesAsync`), the detail rows are deleted along with the master and even the stockings are updated as expected.

The problem only comes with Cascade deletion from the context. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Why are you using cursors instead of set-based updated? Thats gonna be painful for performance.

Comment: If you profile what EF is doing and capture the exact SQL it is using, then see if that SQL behaves the same in SSMS.

Comment: EF can't bypass triggers. If there is a statement that deletes a detail record (either directly or through cascading) the trigger must fire. In the end, it's ADO.Net that runs a SQL statement that EF happened to have composed, but at that point it's just that: a SQL statement in text.

Comment: EF could disable a trigger though? (I have no idea whether it would) but be worth capturing the exact SQL being run.

Comment: Also are you sure the trigger isn't running? Because it might be running, but have different data to what you expect, and hence not behaving as your expect (this seems to be a common issue with cascades from reading around).

Comment: @DaleK how do you suggest profiling the SQL considering I am using VS for Mac?

Comment: You can run extended events, or start a trace via code, it can be read without Profiler. You can also log all inserted /deleted rows from the inside of the trigger into some global table. Or get a real computer. For what i can see, EF doesn't alter triggers, but i wonder if perhaps there is some error occuring which is swallowed which lead to the above behaviour

Comment: [They did](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78079315/2029983), @DaleK

Comment: *" how do you suggest profiling the SQL considering I am using VS for Mac?!"* Azure Data Studio.

Comment: Please don't delete and re-ask the same question. Improve the original, and it will enter the re-open queue.

Comment: @ThomA it worked for him here, he got an answer

Comment: @DaleK i actually upvoted cause i'm curious what the error is :D

Comment: I think your comment to me was meant for Dale, @siggemannen ? If not, apologies, but what worked for him?

Comment: @ThomA deleting and reposting. The other question got closed i guess

Comment: @DaleK *EF could disable a trigger though?* -- It's not going to run disable trigger statements, there's nothing in EF that does that.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way that EF Core is bypassing your triggers. There must be a bug in the trigger logic.

Your trigger as it stands may or may not be correct, but it uses a huge amount of Bad Stuff:

- Cursors, instead of a joined update.
- You would need to join `inserted` and `deleted` using a full-join, although in this case, because you want a qiantity difference, it could make more sense to use `UNION ALL` and `GROUP BY`.
- Use of three-part column names.
- Lack of table aliases to make it more readable.
- Checking `TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL` without passing an object ID.
- One would hope that `(WarehouseId, ComponentId, ColorId)` is a primary or unique key in both tables, otherwise you may end up updating multiple rows.

Your trigger should look like this:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER dbo.tr_update_stocks
ON dbo.WarehouseComponentLoadRows
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 OR TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL(@@PROCID) > 1
    RETURN;

SET NOCOUNT ON;


UPDATE wc
  SET
      StockQuantity     += i.DiffQuantity,
      AvailableQuantity += i.DiffQuantity
FROM
    dbo.WarehouseComponents wc
JOIN (
    SELECT
      i.WarehouseId,
      i.ComponentId,
      i.ColorId,
      SUM(i.Quantity) AS DiffQuantity
    FROM (
        SELECT
          i.WarehouseId,
          i.ComponentId,
          i.ColorId,
          i.Quantity
        FROM inserted i

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
          d.WarehouseId,
          d.ComponentId,
          d.ColorId,
          -d.Quantity
        FROM deleted d
    ) i
    GROUP BY
      i.WarehouseId,
      i.ComponentId,
      i.ColorId
) i ON i.WarehouseId = wc.WarehouseId
   AND i.ComponentId = wc.ComponentId
   AND i.ColorId = wc.ColorId;
```

---

**To be honest,** if you all you want is the total child quantity then **you should probably just use a view** instead of triggers.

```sql
CREATE VIEW dbo.TotalWarehouseComponentLoadRows
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS

SELECT
  wcl.WarehouseId,
  wcl.ComponentId,
  wcl.ColorId,
  SUM(wcl.Quantity) AS Quantity,
  COUNT_BIG(*) AS Count
FROM dbo.WarehouseComponentLoadRows wcl
GROUP BY
  wcl.WarehouseId,
  wcl.ComponentId,
  wcl.ColorId;
```

For extra performance, you could make that into an indexed view.

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX ON WarehouseComponentLoadRows
  (WarehouseId, ComponentId, ColorId);
```

Comment: TIL `@@ROWCOUNT` comes pre-populated into a trigger! Cool!

Comment: Yes but you *must* read it on the very first line, and when using `MERGE` it contains the total rowcount even though the trigger is fired three times, in some cases with 0 rows.

Comment: So with a merge, you'd get the same rowcount for each of the 3 firings? And even `set nocount on` must come after? Black magic!

Comment: @Charlieface I replaced my trigger with this (said that there's an error in the alias here:         `SELECT
          i.WarehouseId,
          i.ComponentId,
          i.ColorId,
          -i.Quantity
        FROM deleted d` and also in the group by later...but unfortunately it keeps on working only if I remove the rows from the engine. Not from within the integration test of my application...

Comment: @Charlieface don't worry, I had fixed it already, but it still doesn't work. This thing is making me crazy...

Comment: See also further edit.

Comment: @ImproveSoftware Now you mention you see this in integration test. Just to be sure, I assume these tests are on SQL Server as well?

Comment: Did you run the profiler to see what SQL is being sent?

Comment: @GertArnold yes everything is run against SQL Server. I didn’t run the profiler yet, I tried every possible solution. In the end, out of rush, I “solved” by deleting all the related rows and then deleting the master by its PK and finally calling a SaveChangesAsync…